# How to display progress percentage in UI in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, progress-bar

I have a button in my Rails application. When it is clicked, around 5 stored procedures run (sequentially) in the background. It takes around 60 seconds for all of them to complete.

Until then, I would like to display some kind of a progress bar (or a spinner that shows percentage of progress) in the UI so that the user does not get a feeling that the application just hangs.

So, if 1 out of 5 stored procedures are complete, then we could should show the progress as 20%; if 2 stored procedures are complete, then show the progress as 40% and so on.

What is the best way to do this?

(Ajax spinners don't seem to have a provision to display % progress)

Comment: I have replied to your question please check @Biju

Answer (score 1):

you can use bootstrap progress bar and update the values from js or jquery. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp) are the examples.

Comment: Thanks @wasipeer - but I am not clear on how to display percentage completion based on the number of stored procedures that have successfully completed. Any inputs on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you have to store the state of completed actions in database and make an ajax call in loop for check the competed actions count. After ajax call update the counts in the progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

**Js** :

**HTML** :

```js
var i = 0;
fill_bar();
function fill_bar(){
  setInterval(function() {
      var art = i;
      doSomethingWith(art)
      if(i >= 5) {return false;}
  }, 5000); 
}
valuer = 0;
function doSomethingWith(art){
valuer = valuer + 20;
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', valuer+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', valuer);  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
  </div>
</div>
```

You can call the method

```
fill_bar()
```

from controller or after clicking the button.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Just a quick question? How would this script know when a stored procedure is complete so that it can show a progress accordingly?

Comment: so you can the js method from controller for method fill_bar()
in you can pass the valuer i have taken 20 you can pass acording to your requiremnet